# Xcode 7 App Crash on 64Bit devices

Tags: 64-bit, ios9, xcode7

My app was working fine on Xcode 6.x but since updating to Xcode 7 and iOS 9, app crashes at startup on 64Bit devices (Simulator), But works fine on 32Bit devices(Simulator). 
Here is the screen shot from debug window

[image: Debug window]

P.S.

Optimization is None for `Debug`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was caused by old TestFurry SDK which didn't support 64bit devices yet.

Updated the TestFurry SDK and the problem is gone.

Comment: Then how did it link in the first place?

Comment: It was already linked in in the previous version. I was making it ready for 64 bit devices.